# Can immune cells be recruited to an area of inflammation, and later go on to a second?

Tags: cell-biology, immunology, infection, migration, infectious-diseases

With regards to innate or adaptive immune cells... can naive/immature cells such as neutrophils, monocytes, macrophage/dendritic cells or adaptive T-cells be recruited to an area of inflammation, for instance an infection in the gastric mucosa, then leave that area and be recruited to another different area of inflammation? Or once recruited to a site are they unresponsive to other events?